# Strange String ">>>>" turning up in the top of the site

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

On my Joomla site (www.schoolofthaimassage.com) is see a strange string >>>>> turning up above the top bar.

In firebug I see it shows in body tag

```
<body id="jsn-master" class="jsn-textstyle-custom jsn-color-grey jsn-direction-ltr jsn-responsive jsn-mobile jsn-joomla-30 jsn-com-content jsn-view-featured jsn-itemid-107 jsn-homepage" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" style="">
> > > > > 
<noscript><iframe src='//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX' height='0' width='0' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe></noscript>
```

I can't understand where it is coming from? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say just from looking at the source code.

I recommend trying some or all of the following:

1. run a back up and upgrade Joomla and all third party extensions to the latest versions
2. temporarily switch to an alternative site template to see if the issue is related to the currently selected template (maybe a template override is causing the issue?)
3. temporarily disable third party modules to see if this makes any difference
4. temporarily disable third party plugins to see if this makes any difference
5. check the template index.php file to see if it has been manually edited for some reason
6. scan the website for malware if no other explanation can be found